# Bulding with Grunt without concat, uglify and minify

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman-generator, grunt-contrib-uglify, grunt-contrib-concat

I've been trying to build my yo proyect by running `grunt` without concat, uglify and minify with no success. I commented the followings:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    //'concat',
    //'cssmin',
    //'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
    //'htmlmin'
]);
```

I got no errors after it but it's not building the `.css`. Is it the right way to do it? This is my **[Gruntfile.js](https://gist.github.com/labanino/468cdae5889c0d0b977b)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from concatenating, uglifying and minifying your files, these tasks (along with `useminPrepare` and `usemin`, so comment those out too) are also writing assets to the `dist` folder. Now you have to write them in some other way, I suggest using the `copy` task:

```
copy: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
            src: [
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                // ...
```